# Returning a different data type from function using a template

Tags: c++, function, templates, return-value

I am trying to create a function to parse XML and return either a `std::string` or `int` using templates. I have come up with the following code:

```
template <class T>
T queryXml(char *str)
{
     if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
         return evalulate_number(doc);
     else
         return evaluate_string(doc);
}
```

...and calling the function like this:

```
queryXml<int>("/people/name"); //I would like an int returned
queryXml<std::string>("/people/name"); //I would like a string returned
```

But I get errors saying `cannot convert pugi::string_t{aka std::basic_string<char>} to int in return`. Is there a better and cleaner way to do this using templates? Thank you!

Comment: The template function is instantialized as a whole so this will not work - like it would not work if I put either of the types as the return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template specialization.

```
// The general form in your algorithm is to use a string...
template <class T>
T queryXml(char *str)
{
   return evaluate_string(doc);
}

// ...and you want special behavior when using an int
template <>
int queryXml(char *str)
{
   return evalulate_number(doc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, you cannot have a function with two distinct return types. You can, however, have multiple functions with similar names and distinct return types. You can accomplish this with either function overloading or template specialization. In your case, function overloading cannot be used because you want the same function signature for all return types.

Here is how you might specialize your template for each intended type:

```
#include <string>

int evaluate_number() { return 87; }
std::string evaluate_string() { return "hi\n"; }

template <class T>
T queryXml(const char *str);

template<>
int queryXml<int>(const char *str) {
  return evaluate_number();
}

template<>
std::string queryXml<std::string>(const char *str) {
  return evaluate_string();
}

int main () {
  int i = queryXml<int>("/people/name"); //I would like an int returned
  std::string s = queryXml<std::string>("/people/name"); //I would like a string returned
}
```